# How can I force cv.glmnet not to drop one specific variable?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, glmnet

I am running a regression with 67 observasions and 32 variables. I am doing variable selection using cv.glmnet function from the glmnet package. There is one variable I want to force into the model. (It is dropped during normal procedure.) How can I specify this condition in cv.glmnet?

Thank you!

My code looks like the following:

```
glmntfit <- cv.glmnet(mydata[,-1], mydata[,1])
coef(glmntfit, s=glmntfit$lambda.1se)
```

And the variable I want is mydata[,2].

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This can be achieved by providing a `penalty.factor` vector, as described in `?glmnet`. A penalty factor of `0` indicates that the "variable is always included in the model", while `1` is the default.

```
glmntfit <- cv.glmnet(mydata[,-1], mydata[, 1], 
                      penalty.factor=c(0, rep(1, ncol(mydata) - 2)))
```

Comment: `penalty.factor = (names(mydata)[1:...] == 'VAR_TO_PENALIZE')` would be a more elegant way to pick out that variable.

Comment: Is there a possibility that even after setting penalty.factor of a variable to 0, it is still not forced into the model ?

Comment: @melwin_jose It's possible. For example, you centered y and you have a constant column in your X, then coef of that columns should be zero. But in most of the time it won't be zero.