# LASSO regression - Force variables in glmnet with tidymodels

Tags: r, glmnet, tidymodels

I am doing feature selection using LASSO regression with `tidymodels` and `glmnet`.

It is possible to force variables in `glmnet` by using the `penalty.factors` argument (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24148805/how-can-i-force-cv-glmnet-not-to-drop-one-specific-variable) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64509382/how-to-force-cva-glmnet-to-include-speficied-variables-in-elastic-net-regressi), for example).

Is it possible to do the same using `tidymodels` ?

```r
library(tidymodels)
library(vip)
library(forcats)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

# Define data split
datasplit = rsample::initial_split(mtcars, prop=0.8)
data_training = rsample::training(datasplit)
data_testing = rsample::testing(datasplit)

# Model specifications - should penalty.factors go here?
model_spec = parsnip::linear_reg(penalty = tune::tune(),
                                 mixture = 1) %>%
  parsnip::set_engine("glmnet")
# Model recipe
rec = recipe(mpg ~ ., mtcars)
# Model workflow
wf = workflows::workflow() %>%
  workflows::add_recipe(rec) %>%
  workflows::add_model(model_spec)
# Resampling
data_resample = rsample::vfold_cv(data_training,
                                  repeats = 3,
                                  v = 2)
hyperparam_grid = dials::grid_regular(dials::penalty(),
                                      levels = 100)
# Define metrics
metrics = yardstick::metric_set(yardstick::rsq,
                                yardstick::mape,
                                yardstick::mpe)
# Tune the model
tune_grid_results = tune::tune_grid(
  wf,
  resamples = data_resample,
  grid = hyperparam_grid,
  metrics = metrics
)
# Collect and finalise best model
selected_model = tune_grid_results %>%
  tune::select_best("mape")

final_model = tune::finalize_workflow(wf, selected_model)

final_model_fit = final_model %>%
  parsnip::fit(data_training) %>%
  workflows::extract_fit_parsnip()
# Plot variables importance
t_importance = final_model_fit %>%
  vip::vi(lambda = selected_model$penalty) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    Importance = Importance,
    Variable = forcats::fct_reorder(Variable, Importance)
  ) %>%
  data.table() %>%
  setorder( - Importance)

t_importance %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Importance, y = Variable, fill = Sign)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  labs(y = NULL) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: [set_engine()](https://parsnip.tidymodels.org/reference/set_engine.html) lets you pass engine-specific arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment above, you can [pass engine-specific arguments like `penalty.factor` in `set_engine()`](https://parsnip.tidymodels.org/reference/set_engine.html#details):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)
library(vip)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'vip'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:utils':
#> 
#>     vi

datasplit <- initial_split(mtcars, prop = 0.8)
car_train <- training(datasplit)
car_test <- testing(datasplit)
car_folds <- vfold_cv(car_train, repeats = 3, v = 2)
```

You can pass `penalty.factor` here to the model specification as an engine-specific argument:

```r
glmnet_spec <- linear_reg(penalty = tune(), mixture = 1) %>%
   set_engine("glmnet", penalty.factor = c(0, rep(1, 7), 0, 0))

car_wf <- workflow(mpg ~ ., glmnet_spec)
glmnet_res <- tune_grid(car_wf, resamples = car_folds, grid = 5)
glmnet_res
#> # Tuning results
#> # 2-fold cross-validation repeated 3 times 
#> # A tibble: 6 × 5
#>   splits          id      id2   .metrics          .notes          
#>   <list>          <chr>   <chr> <list>            <list>          
#> 1 <split [12/13]> Repeat1 Fold1 <tibble [10 × 5]> <tibble [0 × 3]>
#> 2 <split [13/12]> Repeat1 Fold2 <tibble [10 × 5]> <tibble [0 × 3]>
#> 3 <split [12/13]> Repeat2 Fold1 <tibble [10 × 5]> <tibble [0 × 3]>
#> 4 <split [13/12]> Repeat2 Fold2 <tibble [10 × 5]> <tibble [0 × 3]>
#> 5 <split [12/13]> Repeat3 Fold1 <tibble [10 × 5]> <tibble [0 × 3]>
#> 6 <split [13/12]> Repeat3 Fold2 <tibble [10 × 5]> <tibble [0 × 3]>

best_penalty <- select_best(glmnet_res, "rmse")

final_fit <- car_wf %>%
   finalize_workflow(best_penalty) %>%
   fit(data = car_train) %>%
   extract_fit_parsnip()


final_fit %>%
   vi(lambda = best_penalty$penalty) %>%
   mutate(Variable = fct_reorder(Variable, Importance)) %>%
   ggplot(aes(x = Importance, y = Variable, fill = Sign)) +
   geom_col() +
   scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
   labs(y = NULL) +
   theme_minimal()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

This does require that you know the number of predictors when you create the model specification, which can become challenging for a complex recipe including many feature engineering steps.